# Could not find AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension.apk

Tags: android, box2d

Im developing an android app with andEngien, and it all worked fine untill I tryed to use AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension. Now I get the error:

```
AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension] Could not find AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension.apk!
```

I suspect the problem was how I imported everything. In the Box2dExtention project under properties>android, I have the "is Library" box ticked, and I have andEngien in the reference box below it, with the green check.

In the andEngien project under properties>android, I have the box ticked and nothing in the reference box.

In my app's propertys>android I dont have the box ticked, and I have andEngien in the reference box.

Do I have this setup correctly? How can I fix this?

thanks,
Jason.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add the project Box2dExtension as library in your application's build path/properties.

Comment: Goto your project's properties <project>->properties->Android. In the second section of the window (below the Is Library option) click on Add and choose the appropriate Library project (in your case it should be Box2dExtension) and click OK. Then you should be good to go.